# Getting servicestack working on monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android, monodevelop, servicestack

I'm trying to reference the servicestack dlls in a new monodroid project and I'm getting build errors.

I grabbed the dlls from here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoDroid

And I'm getting the error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Found a conflict between : 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference.

Any advice on how to fix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest check-in in `ServiceStack.Text.Android` has broken the build. However it is easy to fix.

Check-out both `ServiceStack` and `ServiceStack.Text`.

Open up the `ServiceStack.Text.Android` project, then add a link in the `Common` folder to the file `ServiceStack.Text\src\ServiceStack.Text\Common\DeserializeKeyValuePair.cs`. Build `ServiceStack.Text.Android` and build the ServiceStack Android solution. Now you should have all the files needed in `ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common.Android\bin\Debug` and `ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common.Android\bin\Release`.

I have also put them up on my Dropbox for download here:

- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2991343/ServiceStack.Android/ServiceStack.Common.dll
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2991343/ServiceStack.Android/ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll
- https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2991343/ServiceStack.Android/ServiceStack.Text.dll

I do not take any responsibility for the hosted files!

**EDIT:**
Pushed fix to my fork: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ServiceStack.Text and created a Pull request: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/237

Comment: Great :) It will probably pulled soon, so you can build it yourself if you want :)