# Getting Authentication working on Mono for Android with servicestack

Tags: xamarin.android, servicestack

I've got ServiceStack working nicely on the server and with a Windows test client, and now need to get it working in my Mono For Android application.

I've downloaded the following:

- ServiceStack.Common.dll
- ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll
- ServiceStack.Text.dll

from the github tip, and added references to these in my Mono for Android project.

However, we need to use authentication, so need the ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Web namespace to be available for the client, so I can do the following:

```
var c = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:53434");
var authResponse = c.Get(new Auth { UserName = "myusername", Password = "password", RememberMe = true });
```

Looking at my working test client, Auth is defined in *ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll*, so presumably I need to get hold of this DLL, or its source and compile it in my project.

Am I on the right lines here, or is there a simpler way to set things up? I've searched around but can't find a good resource on how to use ServiceStack with Mono For Android - if there is one, please feel free to point me to it!

I note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411301/getting-servicestack-working-on-monodroid) StackOverflow indicates I'm on the right lines - all I might need is *ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll* compiled for Mono For Android.

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to compile the server `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll` for use in any client library as there is a copy of the Auth DTOs is also available in the `ServiceStack.Common.dll` client library at [ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web.AuthDtos.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AuthDtos.cs).

This is possible since both server and client DTOs generate the same wireformat.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. However, the ServiceStack.Common.dll which I pulled from (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/release/latest/MonoDroid) does not have ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web.Auth defined. So will I have to pull down and compile/include ServiceClient.Web.AuthDtos.cs - or is there a ServiceStack.Common.dll available with this included?

Comment: Yeah the MonoDroid/MonoTouch builds are contributed by the community so they can get a bit out of date. Best to compile from src to get the latest version.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'll do then!

Comment: Just downloaded the source and compiled, and all's working now - thanks!

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that I didn't need to download and compile. I had the wrong namespace for Auth, and it was there all the time, as: _ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web.Auth_

Comment: ok yeah, just updated the Q to reflect the right namespace. thx